# How to force merge a branch into master?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I have two branches:

- Master
- 1.1.0

I initiated a pull request to merge 1.1.0 with master. However, there are complex conflicts and it says to use command line to fix the conflicts. There are over 1500 conflicts. I am sure that I want to use the files in 1.1.0 to overwrite files in master. I have found something called 'ours' and 'thiers'. I understand the concept, that i have to use one of those keywords in the command line to choose which branch should keep it's changes.

I want 1.1.0 to overwrite the conflicting files in master. So could anyone please let me know what commands I should do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to force a merge in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434959/whats-the-best-way-to-force-a-merge-in-git)

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the following command.

`$ git push --force <remote> 1.1.0:Master`

Which follows the format of

`$ git push <remote> <local branch name>:<remote branch to push into>`

with `<remote>` being the remote of your repo which is typically `origin`.

Sources:

[How do I push a local Git branch to master branch in the remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423517/how-do-i-push-a-local-git-branch-to-master-branch-in-the-remote#5423655)

[What's the best way to force a merge in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434959/whats-the-best-way-to-force-a-merge-in-git#9435050)

Comment: It is nice to see that you have mentioned the sources as well, but it is more appropriate to mark a question as a duplicate if it actually seems to be the case.

Comment: So all I do is the first command only and it should merge and commit?

Comment: @RoshanGupta Right I get you, thank you (I'm new to contributing on Stack).

Comment: @user5903386 Yes it should force merge into master.